# Can DuckDB read a dynamic set of CSV files? (table of CSV file paths)

Tags: sql, csv, dynamic, duckdb

I have a large set of CSV files to be merged (as in `UNION ALL`) together, but first I want to read only a small subset of them.

I have a set of CSV file paths and I want to use DuckDB's `read_csv` to read them.

Concretely, I have a table `table_csv_paths` with column `csv_file_path VARCHAR`. You'd think I could just `read_csv(csv_file_path)`. All of the following attempts to do so fail:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM table_csv_paths AS csv_file, 
LATERAL read_csv(csv_file.csv_file_path, union_by_name = true, AUTO_DETECT=TRUE) AS t_csv
;
-- Error: IO Error: No files found that match the pattern "csv_file.csv_file_path"

SELECT 
    *
FROM table_csv_paths AS csv_file, LATERAL (
    SELECT * FROM read_csv(csv_file.csv_file_path, union_by_name = true, AUTO_DETECT=TRUE)
) AS t_csv
;
-- Error: IO Error: No files found that match the pattern "csv_file.csv_file_path"


WITH files_agg AS (
    SELECT list(csv_file.csv_file_path) AS csv_file_paths
    FROM table_csv_paths AS csv_file
)
SELECT * FROM files_agg, read_csv(csv_file_paths, union_by_name = true, AUTO_DETECT=TRUE);
-- Error: IO Error: No files found that match the pattern "csv_file_paths"
```

Is there no way to achieve this? This seems like such a natural use case, as data pipelines so often evolve to become more dynamic.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with `read_csv()`. No matter what I tried, even via Python, `read_csv` takes whatever the first argument is as a literal file name. I would suggest filing an issue here [DuckdB issues](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues).

Comment: `from read_csv((select ['a.csv']))` seems to give a "better" error with regards to the task: *"read_csv only accepts constant parameters"*

Answer (score 1):

At the current moment, no, this is not possible, and this limitation can be worked around doing part of the logic outside SQL.

A feature request at https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues it would be handy to keep track of this.

Carlo, working on DuckDB.